# How do I make my CSS animation more responsive to mouse hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I've got a sort of marquee menu that I'm working on, which I want to pause when I hover over it. And for the most part it works. However, when I mouse over the entire container div, it stops, which looks really awkward for some of the shorter text.

I want for the specific text to be moused over, for the animation to pause itself. I've tried using `:hover` on the spans directly, but that doesn't seem to work for some reason. Any tips on how to do this? Code is below.

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 100%;
}

.outer {
  transform: rotate(10deg);
  margin-left: -6vw;
}

.inner {
  font-family: 'Catamaran';
  font-size: calc(2em + 7vw);
  font-weight: 900;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: white;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px;
  letter-spacing: -.9vw;
  line-height: calc(.7em + 1vw);
  animation: marquee 30s linear infinite;
  display: inline-block;
}

.inner span:nth-of-type(2n) {
  font-size: calc(1em + 5vw);
}

.inner span:nth-of-type(2n-1) {
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: rgba(80, 80, 80, 0.753);
}

.switcher {
  position: relative;
  top: 0%;
  animation: switch 30s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
}

@keyframes switch {
  0%,
  50% {
    top: 0%;
  }
  50.01%,
  100% {
    top: 100%;
  }
}

.inner:hover .switcher {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

.inner:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <span class="switcher">PRANAV NAIR</span><br>
    <span class="switcher"><a>ABOUT</a></span><br>
    <span class="switcher">PRANAV NAIR</span><br>
    <span class="switcher"><a>DESIGN</a></span><br>
    <span class="switcher">PRANAV NAIR</span><br>
    <span class="switcher"><a>CODE</a></span><br>
    <span class="switcher">PRANAV NAIR</span><br>
    <span class="switcher"><a>SOCIAL</a></span><br>
    <span class="switcher">PRANAV NAIR</span><br>
    <span class="switcher"><a>BOOK</a></span><br>
    <span class="switcher">PRANAV NAIR</span><br>
    <span class="switcher"><a>BLOG</a></span><br>
    <span>PRANAV NAIR</span><br>
    <span><a>ABOUT</a></span><br>
    <span>PRANAV NAIR</span><br>
    <span><a>DESIGN</a></span><br>
    <span>PRANAV NAIR</span><br>
    <span><a>CODE</a></span><br>
    <span>PRANAV NAIR</span><br>
    <span><a>SOCIAL</a></span><br>
    <span>PRANAV NAIR</span><br>
    <span><a>BOOK</a></span><br>
    <span>PRANAV NAIR</span><br>
    <span><a>BLOG</a></span><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add pointer-events none on the container.

And reset it to auto on the children.

The hover is still triggered on the container, but only when hovering the children

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 100%;
}

.outer {
  transform: rotate(10deg);
  margin-left: -6vw;
}

.inner {
  font-family: 'Catamaran';
  font-size: calc(2em + 7vw);
  font-weight: 900;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: white;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px;
  letter-spacing: -.9vw;
  line-height: calc(.7em + 1vw);
  animation: marquee 30s linear infinite;
  display: inline-block;
}

.inner span:nth-of-type(2n) {
  font-size: calc(1em + 5vw);
}

.inner span:nth-of-type(2n-1) {
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: rgba(80, 80, 80, 0.753);
}

.switcher {
  position: relative;
  top: 0%;
  animation: switch 30s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
}

@keyframes switch {
  0%,
  50% {
    top: 0%;
  }
  50.01%,
  100% {
    top: 100%;
  }
}

.inner:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

.inner {
   pointer-events: none;
   
}

.switcher {
   pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <span class="switcher">PRANAV NAIR</span><br>
    <span class="switcher"><a>ABOUT</a></span><br>
    <span class="switcher">PRANAV NAIR</span><br>
    <span class="switcher"><a>DESIGN</a></span><br>
    <span class="switcher">PRANAV NAIR</span><br>
    <span class="switcher"><a>CODE</a></span><br>
    <span class="switcher">PRANAV NAIR</span><br>
    <span class="switcher"><a>SOCIAL</a></span><br>
    <span class="switcher">PRANAV NAIR</span><br>
    <span class="switcher"><a>BOOK</a></span><br>
    <span class="switcher">PRANAV NAIR</span><br>
    <span class="switcher"><a>BLOG</a></span><br>
    <span>PRANAV NAIR</span><br>
    <span><a>ABOUT</a></span><br>
    <span>PRANAV NAIR</span><br>
    <span><a>DESIGN</a></span><br>
    <span>PRANAV NAIR</span><br>
    <span><a>CODE</a></span><br>
    <span>PRANAV NAIR</span><br>
    <span><a>SOCIAL</a></span><br>
    <span>PRANAV NAIR</span><br>
    <span><a>BOOK</a></span><br>
    <span>PRANAV NAIR</span><br>
    <span><a>BLOG</a></span><br>
  </div>
</div>
```